# excel vba byref type mismatch

Tags: excel, byref, vba

i'm trying to pass the wb_ and ws_variables to the function getinfofromclosedfile below, i keep getting a byref argument mismatch on the wb_name variable.

```
 Sub check_update()

 Dim wb_path, wb_name, ws_name, ws_cell As String

 AGuser = GetUser
 If Dir("c:\users\" & AGuser & "\documents\appraiser_genie\genieold.xlsm") <> "" Then
    wb_path = "c:\users\" & AGuser & "\documents\"
    wb_name = "genieold.xlsm"
    ws_name = "input"
    ws_cell = Cells(17, 2).Address
    Sheets("input").Cells(17, 2).Select = GetInfoFromClosedFile(wb_path, wb_name, ws_name, ws_cell)
   End If
End Sub

Private Function GetInfoFromClosedFile(ByVal wbPath As String, _
    wbName As String, wsName As String, cellRef As String) As Variant
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: On a side note, this: Dim wb_path, wb_name, ws_name, ws_cell As String doesn't do what you think it does, you need to set each one like this: Dim wb_path As String, wb_name As String, ws_name As String, ws_cell As String

Comment: And if you do what @DanDonoghue suggests, your original code should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare the argument with `ByVal` keyword: `ByVal wbName As String, ByVal wsName As String`.

```
Function GetInfoFromClosedFile(ByVal wbPath As String, ByVal wbName As String, ByVal wsName As String, cellRef As String) As Variant
```

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/dim-statement

Declaring Multiple Variables
You can declare several variables in one declaration statement, specifying the variable name for each one, and following each array name with parentheses. Multiple variables are separated by commas.
VB

Dim lastTime, nextTime, allTimes() As Date

Not sure what Dan Donoghue was on about but you can declare multiple variables in this manner (see above link)